# Checking user agent in Fiddler

Tags: c#, fiddler

I would like to filter traffic by "user-agent" and i am using fiddler for that but i cant find any clue on getting "user-agent".

to modify "user-agent" we use this

```
oSession.oRequest["User-Agent"]="Google"
```

but what i should use to read the browser user-agent that fiddler receiving

tried this but return null
    oS.oRequest["User-Agent"];

I know this question may be been asked before but I still haven't seen a satisfactory answer, or a definitive "no, this cannot be done", so I'll ask again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct user agent just google is not user agent. This link may help...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

You can see the user agent string in headers when you capture some traffic on fiddler.